# Update Stops when Dialog Comes in AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

When ever a dialog comes on a scene in andengine the update method stops unless the dialog is dismissed. All I want to do is that whenever a dialog comes the update method should not be stopped it should be running as normal.
Please provide a solution for it.

Comment: How do you expect anybody to answer when you give nothing to work by?

Comment: What do you expect I should give??

Comment: show us the code where you show your dialog

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a Dialog is displayed, onPause() is called on the activity. You can try calling onResume() on your game activity when the Dialog is created.

In GLES1 version (and maybe in GLES2 too somewhere) AndEngine actively prevents you from resuming the game unless you have focus. You could probably create your own version of BaseGameActivity which does not check for this condition.

Comment: congrats for 50 Respect Points :)